# Limit the number of decimal places a user can enter in a GXT grid cell

Tags: gxt

How can I limit the number of decimal places a user can enter in a GXT grid cell.

I can format the column config via column.setNumberFormat(...) but this just rounds the value to the defined format, e.g. #.##, and the user can enter more than two decimal places.

I would like to limit the input as the users types, so that he/she can only enter a max of two decimal places.

Best,
-- Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement a custom Validator and add it to the field:

```
            final ColumnConfig config = new ColumnConfig();
            config.setNumberFormat(NumberFormat.getFormat("#.##"));
            final NumberField field = new NumberField();
            field.setPropertyEditorType(Float.class); // needed to convert from String to Number - default ist Double
            field.setValidator(new com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.form.Validator(){
                public String validate(Field<?> field, String value) {
                    if(value != null){
                         final int index = value.indexOf('.');
                         if(index > -1 && index < value.length() - 3){
                             return "Maximum number of digits is 2!";
                         }
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            });
            final CellEditor cellEditor = new CellEditor(field);
            config.setEditor(cellEditor);
```